# Remove element from the Priority queue

Tags: go, priority-queue, heap, maximumslidingwindow

```
// This example demonstrates a priority queue built using the heap interface.
package main

import (
    "container/heap"
    "fmt"
)

// An Item is something we manage in a priority queue.
type Item struct {
    value    int // The value of the item; arbitrary.
    priority int // The priority of the item in the queue.
    // The index is needed by update and is maintained by the heap.Interface methods.
    index int // The index of the item in the heap.
}

// A PriorityQueue implements heap.Interface and holds Items.
type PriorityQueue []*Item

func (pq PriorityQueue) Len() int { return len(pq) }

func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    // We want Pop to give us the highest, not lowest, priority so we use greater than here.
    return pq[i].value > pq[j].value
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    pq[i], pq[j] = pq[j], pq[i]
    pq[i].index = j
    pq[j].index = i
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    n := len(*pq)
    item := x.(*Item)
    item.index = n
    *pq = append(*pq, item)
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *pq
    n := len(old)
    item := old[n-1]
    item.index = -1 // for safety
    *pq = old[0 : n-1]
    return item
}

// update modifies the priority and value of an Item in the queue.
func (pq *PriorityQueue) update(item *Item, value int, priority int) {
    item.value = value
    item.priority = priority
    heap.Fix(pq, item.index)
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 3, 2, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    k := 3
    result := maxSlidingWindow(nums, k)
    fmt.Println("result", result)
}

func maxSlidingWindow(nums []int, k int) {

    pq := make(PriorityQueue, len(nums))
    res := []int{}

    for i := 0; i < k; i++ {
        pq[i] = &Item{
            value:    nums[i],
            priority: nums[i],
            index:    i,
        }
        res = append(res, nums[i])
    }
    heap.Init(&pq)
    peek := pq[0]
    fmt.Println(peek.value) // its a maxheap and gives the largest element

    temp := heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)
    fmt.Println("temp:", temp)

    remove := heap.Remove(&pq, 0).(*Item)
    // pq = slices.Delete(pq, 5)
    fmt.Println("remove:", remove)
    
    for i:=0;i<len(nums);i++{
    
     //remove the desired element from the priority Queue 
     // insert the next element in the Priority queue
     // peek the highest value 

     }

}
```

I am trying to print the maximum value in a sliding window. Putting the elements of window size, here **k = 3** into the priority queue(Maxheap) and then peek the value.
**"heap.Init(&pq)"** will assign the index in **pq** based on the priority. Look for  **maxSlidingWindow** function, the last **for** loop prints the max element for each window of size k.  If you compare the indices in the **pq** and the nums array the indices will be different. And hence deleting the desired element from the priority queue seems almost impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough. I assume that you want your `maxSlidingWindow` to behave like this:

```
maxSlidingWindow([]int{1, 3, 2,-3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 3)

  returns   -->     []int{3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

To achieve this, one might do the following:

1. Fill a priority queue with the first `k` values from `nums`.

   Your code is putting all values from `nums` into the queue, which does not seem like a moving window approach. And I do doubt if I misunderstand your question.
2. Take the max value from the queue, append it to the `result`.
3. For i from `k` to `len(Data) - 1`:

   1. Discard the `nums[i-k]` element from the priority queue, and push into the queue `nums[i]`.

      You should use use `heap.Remove` to remove an element. Go's `heap.Fix` provides a way to combine the removing and pushing steps.
   2. Take the max value of the modified priority queue, append it to the `result`.

Also, your implementation of the queue has a bug:

```golang
func (pq PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    pq[i], pq[j] = pq[j], pq[i]
    pq[i].index = j // should be: pq[i].index = i
    pq[j].index = i // should be: pq[j].index = j
}
```

#### Removing elements from priority queues

According to the title of the question, it seems you cannot get this part working:

> Discard the `nums[i-k]` element from the priority queue, and push into the queue `nums[i]`

Using Go's `heap`, to modify an item (with `heap.Fix`) or remove one (with `heap.Remove`, an index to that item is required. To get the corresponding index, there are at least two ways.

Note that we need to distinguish from the indices of elements in `nums` and the indices of elements in the queue. I am to refer to the former one as `i` in the following code and the latter, `j`. We know the `i` of the element we want to remove, but since `heap` changes the queue, we need to find `j`.

##### Loop through the queue and find the element

Simple enough. In this way, you may just simplify the `PriorityQueue` type:

```golang
type PriorityQueue []int
// I will skip the heap.Interface part

func maxSlidingWindow(nums []int, k int) []int {
    pq := make(PriorityQueue, k)
    result := make([]int, 0, len(nums)-k+1)

    for i := 0; i < k; i++ {           // 1.
        pq[i] = nums[i]
    }

    heap.Init(&pq)

    result = append(result, pq[0])     // 2.

    for i := k; i < len(nums); i++ {
        for j, value := range pq {     // 3.1.
            if value == nums[i-k] {
                pq[j] = nums[i]        // Instead of removing then pushing
                heap.Fix(&pq, j)       // We modify the content with heap.Fix
                break
            }
        }
        result = append(result, pq[0]) // 3.2.
    }
    return result
}
```

It handles duplicate values correctly.

##### Keep a external `i -> j` mapping

Below is just a possible way doing it and may not be that elegant. I use a `CircularArray` to keep our mapping:

```golang
type CircularArray []int

func (a CircularArray) wrapped(index int) int {
    return index % len(a)
}

func (a CircularArray) Get(index int) int {
    return a[a.wrapped(index)]
}

func (a CircularArray) Set(index int, value int) {
    a[a.wrapped(index)] = value
}

func (a CircularArray) Swap(i, j int) {
    ii, jj := a.wrapped(i), a.wrapped(j)
    a[ii], a[jj] = a[jj], a[ii]
}
```

```golang
type PriorityQueue struct {
    Window           []int         // The queue
    IndicesOfIndices CircularArray // `i -> j` mapping
}

// func (pq *PriorityQueue) Len() ...
func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {} // don't use
func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} { return nil } // don't use

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Less(a, b int) bool {
    return pq.Window[a] > pq.Window[b]
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Swap(a, b int) {
    pq.Window[a], pq.Window[b] = pq.Window[b], pq.Window[a]
    pq.IndicesOfIndices.Swap(a, b)
}

func maxSlidingWindow(nums []int, k int) []int {
    pq := PriorityQueue{
        Window:           make([]int, 0, k),
        IndicesOfIndices: make(CircularArray, k),
    }

    result := make([]int, 1, len(nums)-k+1)

    for i := 0; i < k; i++ {
        pq.PushWithIndex(nums[i], i)                          // 1.
    }

    heap.Init(&pq)

    result[0] = pq.Window[0]                                  // 2.

    for i := k; i < len(nums); i++ {
        result = append(result, pq.NextWithIndex(nums[i], i)) // 3.
    }

    return result
}

// Pushes into the queue and sets up the `i -> j` mapping
func (pq *PriorityQueue) PushWithIndex(value int, i int) {
    pq.IndicesOfIndices.Set(i, len(pq.Window))
    pq.Window = append(pq.Window, value)
}

// Updates the queue and returns the max element
func (pq *PriorityQueue) NextWithIndex(pushed int, i int) int {
    j := pq.IndicesOfIndices.Get(i) // 3.1.
    pq.Window[j] = pushed
    heap.Fix(pq, j)
    return pq.Window[0]             // 3.2.
}
```

Comment: I was in testing mode and forgot to restrict the first loop to k times. I was curious to see how the indices corresponding to the value change when heap.Init(&pq) hits. Also, the Swap func, I know I have changed values. Still doesn't make any difference. My focus is more on a func that finds an element and deletes it. If I have to do the same by running a loop will cost more. Standard libraries will do it on log(n) time complexity. Your above circular queue code gives me an error. Please cross check.

Comment: Would you please post the error message? (The above code is *intentionally incomplete* to highlight the algorithm. Simply copy and pasting will definitely give you an error.)

Comment: cannot use &pq (value of type *PriorityQueue) as type heap.Interface in argument to heap.Init:
        *PriorityQueue does not implement heap.Interface (missing Len method)

Comment: @Gourav Yes, I guess the definition of `Len` would be simple enough to skipped. `func (pq *PriorityQueue) Len() int { return len(pq.Window) }`.